# Can I get Clazz.class on a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I am trying to invoke `EasyMock.isA(Class<T>)` on a `List<MyType>`. Is there a way to do it without warnings?

I've tried the following:

```
isA(List<MyType>.class);  // doesn't compile
isA(List.<MyType>class);  // syntax error on tokens (MyType), misplaced construct
isA(List.class);          // This gives a warning: Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<MyType>
```

**EDIT**:

Jakub HR gave the correct answer. However, for my particular situation where I require this for EasyMock, I can simply use

```
EasyMock.<List<MyType>>anyObject()
```

Comment: due to type parameters erasure in JVM, you cannot check it (unless you use a custom generic List class which also stores inside an actual `Class<?>` object of corresponding type (which will have to be provided manually))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From *Effective Java*:

> There are two minor exceptions to the rule that you should not use raw types in new code, both of which stem from the fact that generic type information is erased at runtime. You must use raw types in class literals. The specification does not permit the use of parameterized types (though it does permit array types and primitive types). In other words, `List.class`, `String[].class`, and int.class are all legal, but `List<String>.class` `and List<?>.class` are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as below:

```
Class<T> persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Comment: What am I invoking `getClass()` on? `this`? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: getClass() as in `new ArrayList<MyType>() {}.getClass();`. Although never tried this even once, but theoretically this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Due to type parameters erasure in JVM, you cannot check it (unless you use a custom generic List class which also stores inside an actual `Class<?>` object of corresponding type (which will have to be provided manually))
This is because at run time there is no way to know generic type parameters — `List<String>`, `List<MyType>`, etc. all "get erased" to `List<Object>` (or just `List` — no difference) at run time. Maybe you also want to read [a more deep example out of the web](http://javapapers.com/core-java/type-erasure/)

Comment: You are wrong. List<String> is changed to List not to List<Object>

Comment: @JakubHr this is the same. `List` is just a "raw type", it's different at language level, but not in the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested/accepted answer is not *quite* correct.  Here is a more complete answer:

`myMock.myMeth(isA(List.class));                 // #1 fails if arg == null, warnings`
`myMock.myMeth(EasyMock.<List<MT>> anyObject()); // #2 succeeds even when arg == null`
`myMock.myMeth(anyObject())                      // #3 same as #2`

`myMock.myMeth(EasyMock.<List<MT>> notNull());   // #4 same as #1, no warnings!`
`myMock.myMeth(notNull());                       // #5 prob same as #1, less informative`

So if you really want the same behavior as isA(), use notNull() rather than anyObject().  Note that, when using either anyObject() or notNull(), you're really depending on the compiler to have ensured that the called code did in fact pass in a proper List.  If you somehow managed to 'fake' some other object into the call (nearly impossible), EasyMock is not going to catch it with anyObject() or notNull().